# How to generate a sequence that increments alternately

Tags: r

I would like to create a sequence starting at 2 and ending at 65, which increments first by 3, then by 1, then by 3, then by 1, and so on, giving an end result that looks like this:

```
sequence(2,5,6,9,10,13,14,17,18,21,22,25,26,29,30,33,34,37,38,41,42,45,46,49,50,53,54,57,58,61,62,65)
```

Does anyone know how to go about generating such a sequence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easily generalizable

```
begin = 2
end = 65
d = c(3, 1)
l = length(d)
cumsum(c(begin, rep(d, len = (end-l)/l)))

[1]  2  5  6  9 10 13 14 17 18 21 22 25 26 29 30 33 34 37 38 41 42 45 46 49 50 53 54 57 58 61 62 65
```

Comment: nice approach!!

Answer (score 6):

Using recycling in R, first create all numbers between 3&65 and from that just selecting alternate pairs! and after that attach the 2 to it.

To select the alternate pairs , i choose the following pattern : c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE) such that first 2 are rejected and next 2 are accepted.
For e.g. c(3,4,5,6)[c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE)]  means that 3,4 are rejected and 5,6 are accepted

```
c(2,c(3:65)[c(F,F,T,T)])
[1]  2  5  6  9 10 13 14 17 18 21 22 25 26 29 30 33 34 37 38 41 42 45 46 49 50 53 54 57 58 61 62
[32] 65
```

---

Since I'm working on Rcpp, I thought shall just explore on that. Thanks for this question. Completed my first assignment in Rcpp :)

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction('NumericVector func(int start, int end){
        int j = 0;
        int len = ceil((end-start)/2);
        if (end%2 != 0){
          len+=1;
        }
        Rcpp::NumericVector result(len);

        result[j++] = start;

        int i = start;
        while(j <= len){
            if (j%2 == 0){
                result[j++] = i+1;
                i+=1;
            }
            else {
                result[j++] = i+3;
                i+=3;
            }
        }              
        return result;
  }')

> func(2,65)
 [1]  2  5  6  9 10 13 14 17 18 21 22 25 26 29 30 33 34 37 38 41 42 45 46 49 50 53 54 57 58 61 62 65
> func(2,20)
[1]  2  5  6  9 10 13 14 17 18
> func(1,10)
[1] 1 4 5 8
```

Comment: #joel.wilson Sir thank you for the solution Much Appreciated, requesting you could you please explain the c(F,F,T,T) .

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not generalizable, but

```
> sort(c(seq(2,65,4), seq(5,65,4)))
[1]  2  5  6  9 10 13 14 17 18 21 22 25 26 29 30 33 34 37 38 41 42 45 46 49 50 53 54 57 58 61 62 65
```

Comment: Good answer - but an explanation of the code helps people understand what they're doing. A novice might not know what `c` means, or what all the arguments mean in `seq`.

Answer (score 1):

I am providing you the logic implement it in the programming language that you are using.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int start = 2, end = 65;
    std::cout << start;
    cout<<"\n";
    for(int i=start;i<=end;i++){
       if(i == start){
          cout<<i+3;
          cout<<"\n";
          i +=3;
       }else{
          cout<<i;
          cout<<"\n";
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> Implemented in C++;

Comment: does this logic work? only when i==2 you are incrementing by 3 rest of the times it will be incremented only by 1 right? did i get this wrong?

Comment: Yes it will work as I am not hardcoding the value 2 but instead of that I am using start to compare. And yes it will work for any starting to ending value. @joel.wilson

Comment: The question was about R language not C++

Comment: Yes! True sorry for that but I mentioned that it is implemented in c++. From now onwards I will take care buddy @UweBlock

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get the first n terms of the sequence, we have

[image]

```
n <- 32   # get first 32 terms
x <- 1:n
2+as.integer(x/2)*3+as.integer((x-1)/2)

# [1]  2  5  6  9 10 13 14 17 18 21 22 25 26 29 30 33 34 37 38 41 42 45 46 
#     49 50 53 54 57 58 61 62 65
```

Comment: Mathematical operations in R are vectorized, so no need of `sapply`. Much better `x<-1:n;2+as.integer(x/2)*3+as.integer((x-1)/2)`.

Comment: sure that will make it faster